# Automatic rendering in command line

Tags: python

I want automatically make images of some 3d model from different camera positions. I think Blender ideally for this task because has python support.

I tried:

```
blender -b audi.blend -x 1 -o //render -a
```

Error: Cannot render, no camera

So I need:

1)load blend model

2)set camera position

3)render and save image to disk

PS.
I completely noob in Blender so sorry for stupid question, but I can't find end-to-end tutorial.

Comment: The best thing you can do is try to start whatever task it is you're trying to do (I don't know what 'automatic' means in this situation) and when you come up against a specific problem, ask about that. So if loading a model is the first task and you can't work out how to do that, then that would be your first question.